# Trouble figuring out how to get my button to submit comment

Tags: php, functions, comments, javascript

I have a text area in the sidebar (sidebar-chat.php) of my posts page with an input that is an image. When this image is clicked, the comment is supposed to submit. I am just having trouble figuring out how to make this happen. Below is a screenshot of what it looks like, as well as the HTML. Am I supposed to add a function to functions.php to get this to happen? Any advice would be great!

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="font-wrap">
  <div class="wrapper">

    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="talk-bubble comment" tabindex="4" placeholder="Enter comment..."></textarea>

    <p class="sign-in">
      Post a new comment
    </p>
    <input class="comment-img" type="image" tabindex="5" alt="Submit Comment" value="Submit Comment" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/sign-in.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You were missing the  tags and the "type" attribute for the  tag. The php tag at the bottom echo's the result that was input in the textarea. Read this http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp
it should help you get started.

```
<div class="font-wrap">
<div class="wrapper">
<form action="" method="post">
 <textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="talk-bubblecomment" tabindex="4" placeholder="Enter comment..."></textarea>

<p class="sign-in">
  Post a new comment
</p>
<input type="submit"  value="Submit Comment" />
</form>
<?php echo "$_POST[comment]";?>
```